# Powering a Raspberry Pi from a smartphone power bank

Tags: power-supply

I'm looking to power a raspberry pi model 3 for a portable project. If I were to power it from a [10000mAh power bank](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013UEBCPE) (meant to charge smartphones), would the Pi be ok off this power supply, and if so, how long would it last on average? I am not looking to plug in any devices to the Pi, as my project solely requires software.

Comment: Part of the reason I'm closing this is because no one can promise you a power bank is going to work well with a Pi 3 without knowing some (probably not publicized) details about the power bank **regardless of amperage**.  In general they are intended for *recharging other batteries*, moreover, via the intermediate circuitry of another device, a purpose which may have different *and contrary* requirements to *powering active devices*.  In short: It's a gamble, you can try it, no one can promise you it will work, but it may or may not.

Answer (score 1):

Try it and see! [Link](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#power-supply) suggests 400mA so (10,000 / 400) * (3.3 / 5) ~ 16 hours.

Unfortunately Power Banks differ widely in their ACTUAL performance.